# How to block Internet access for some devices on given hours?

Tags: networking, internet, firewall, quota

I have a Ubuntu machine (15.10) running as a gateway which routes / firewalls  traffic between a LAN an Internet.

I need to block Internet access during some hours for specific devices on the LAN.

Before jumping into scripting `iptables` rules which will be enabled/disabled via `cron`, I wanted to check whether there is no such a service/program already existing. Neither a repository check nor Google searches brought in anything relevant.

Comment: If you do decide to go the iptables route, please be aware that you should not need to involve cron, but rather you can use the time module in iptables. I tried it once and it worked great. see [also](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247375).